# UICollectionViewCell - Round Downloaded Image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview, kingfisher

I am trying to set a collectionView with round images I get using KingFisher (image caching library).

I am not sure what I should set with round corner, the imageView or the cell itself. Even if the cell is round the image seems to fill the square.

So far I am using this code (If I dont set it after I change the image its square):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
...
if let path = user.profilePictureURL {
                    if let url = URL(string: path) {
                        cell.profilePictureImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
                        cell.profilePictureImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.profilePictureImageView.frame.width/2.0
                    }
                }
```

And the ImageView :

```
class ProfilePicture : UIImageView {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        self.commonInit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit(){
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.layer.frame.width/2.0
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

But the first time it downloads the images , they are like this (cell background is blue)

[image: Horizontal CollectionView]

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
extension UIImageView {

   func setRounded() {
      let radius = CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) / 2
      self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
      self.layer.masksToBounds = true
   }
}
```

then call the method as below:

```
imageView.setRounded()
```

Comment: Ι even call this on the callback of the image caching library (Kingfisher), But I still the same error. (not on all the cells , seems random)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a circle by adjusting height (in portrait) instead of width:

```
self.layer.cornerRadius = self.layer.frame.height/2.0
```

you'll have to adjust your contentMode.scaleAspect if you are unhappy with the results. By adjusting on the long edge you can get a circle but you won't see the entire image.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a circle in the image with a extension of UIView

```
extension UIImage {
var circleMask: UIImage {
    let square = size.width < size.height ? CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.width) : CGSize(width: size.height, height: size.height)
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: square))
    imageView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    imageView.image = self
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = square.width/2
    //imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    //imageView.layer.borderWidth = 5
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.bounds.size)
    imageView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return result!
}}
```